# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (22500,3) into shape (1)

Tags: python, pickle

I relied on the code mentioned, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29781976/cpickle-very-large-amount-of-data), but with minor edits. The version that I have is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import _pickle as cPickle
from PIL import Image
import sys,os

pixels = []
labels = []
traindata = []
data=[]

directory = 'C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\Testing\\images'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        floc = file
        im = Image.open(str(directory) + '\\' + floc)
        pix = np.array(im.getdata())
        pixels.append(pix)
        labels.append(1)

pixels = np.array(pixels)
labels = np.array(labels)
traindata.append(pixels)
traindata.append(labels)
traindata = np.array(traindata)
# do the same for validation and test data
# put all data and labels into 'data' array
cPickle.dump(data,open('data.pkl','wb'))
```

When I run the code, I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pickle_data.py", line 24, in <module>
    traindata=np.array(traindata)
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (22500,3) into shape (1)
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand the structure of `traindata`, I replaced your `pixels.append(pix)` with `pixels.append(pix[np.ix_([1,2,3],[0,1,2])])` to have some toy example. Then I get that `traindata` is

```
[array([[[16, 13, 15],
         [16, 13, 15],
         [16, 13, 15]]]), array([1])]
```

When you tried to transform `traindata` to numpy array you got error as it consists of subarrays of different sizes. You can either save each one of the subarrays in a separate numpy array, or you can do it like that:

```
traindata = np.array([traindata[0][0],traindata[1]], dtype=object)
```

By using `dtype=object`, you can create numpy array consists of elements of different sizes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you kindly explain what [0][0] refers to here?. I belive the result returned is the same as "pixels = np.array(pixels)". How would we have the pixels and labels value togethers, especially that they are appended in the example.

Comment: @Simplicity, see my update. I think you should save them separately if you want to save it as numpy array.

Comment: @Simplicity, see the "edit" part. this seems to work and allow creating numpy array with objects of different sizes.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for your kind support.