# Python - AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, numpy, pickle

This is related to my question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42941668/valueerror-could-not-broadcast-input-array-from-shape-22500-3-into-shape-1).

I now have the updated code as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import _pickle as cPickle
from PIL import Image
import sys,os

pixels = []
labels = []
traindata = []
i = 0

directory = 'C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\Testing\\images'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        floc = file
        im = Image.open(str(directory) + '\\' + floc)
        pix = np.array(im.getdata())
        pixels.append(pix)
        labels.append(1)
        pixels = np.array(pixels)
        labels = np.array(labels)
        traindata.append(pixels)
        traindata.append(labels)
        traindata = np.array([traindata[i][i],traindata[1]], dtype=object)
        i = i + 1

# do the same for validation and test data
# put all data and labels into 'data' array
cPickle.dump(traindata,open('data.pickle','wb'))

FILE = open("data.pickle", 'rb')
content = cPickle.load(FILE)
print (content)
```

When having only one image, the code runs fine. But, when I add another image or more, I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pickle_data.py", line 17, in <module>
    pixels.append((pix))
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: `traindata = np.array([traindata[i][i],traindata[1]], dtype=object)` - why are you doing that? That makes no sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        floc = file
        im = Image.open(str(directory) + '\\' + floc)
        pix = np.array(im.getdata())
        pixels.append(pix)
        labels.append(1)   # append(i)???
```

So far ok. But you want to leave `pixels` as a list until you are done with the iteration.

```
pixels = np.array(pixels)
labels = np.array(labels)
```

You had this indention right in your other question.  What happened?  [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42941668/valueerror-could-not-broadcast-input-array-from-shape-22500-3-into-shape-1)

Iterating, collecting values in a list, and then at the end joining things into a bigger array is the right way.  To make things clear I often prefer to use notation like:

```
alist = []
for ..
    alist.append(...)
arr = np.array(alist)
```

If names indicate something about the nature of the object I'm less likely to get errors like yours.

I don't understand what you are trying to do with `traindata`.  I doubt if you need to build it during the loop.  `pixels` and `labels` have the basic information.

That

```
traindata = np.array([traindata[i][i],traindata[1]], dtype=object)
```

comes from the previous question.  I'm not sure you understand that answer.

```
traindata = []
traindata.append(pixels)
traindata.append(labels)
```

if done outside the loop is just

```
traindata = [pixels, labels]
```

`labels` is a 1d array, a bunch of 1s (or [0,1,2,3...] if my guess is right).  `pixels` is a higher dimension array.  What is its shape?

Stop right there.  There's no point in turning that list into an array.  You can save the list with `pickle`.

You are copying code from an earlier question, and getting the formatting wrong.  [cPickle very large amount of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29781976/cpickle-very-large-amount-of-data)

Answer (score 13):

Numpy arrays do not have an append method. Use the Numpy append function instead:

```
import numpy as np

array_3 = np.append(array_1, array_2, axis=n)
# you can either specify an integer axis value n or remove the keyword argument completely
```

For example, if array_1 and array_2 have the following values:

```
array_1 = np.array([1, 2])
array_2 = np.array([3, 4])
```

If you call np.append without specifying an axis value, like so:

```
array_3 = np.append(array_1, array_2)
```

array_3 will have the following value:

```
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Else, if you call np.append with an axis value of 0, like so:

```
array_3 = np.append(array_1, array_2, axis=0)
```

array_3 will have the following value:

```
 array([[1, 2],
        [3, 4]])
```

More information on the append function here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html

Comment: He could also avoid converting the lists to arrays during the loop (i.e. move pixels = np.array(pixels) to end of loop)

Comment: Don't use `np.append`, especially not in a loop.  It is inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

`append` on an ndarray is ambiguous; to which axis do you want to append the data? Without knowing precisely what your data looks like, I can only provide an example using `numpy.concatenate` that I hope will help:

```
import numpy as np

pixels = np.array([[3,3]])
pix = [4,4]
pixels = np.concatenate((pixels,[pix]),axis=0)

# [[3 3]
#  [4 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

`pixels = np.array(pixels)` in this line you reassign `pixels`. So, it may not a list anyhow. Though `pixels` is not a list it has no attributes `append`. Does it make sense?